# How to create multiple sub application in one react application that can be extracted at any time?

Tags: reactjs, architecture

How we can create multiple sub application inside a root application with one npm module and one public folder. Is it possible to extract one sub application at any time? how each application can be build separately?

root app - list of all sub apps
--App1
--App2
--App3
......

Comment: what do you mean with sub applications? If you use a router you can provide multiple "apps" in one application. Can you elaborate a little bit further what you mean?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.